# How to write md5 signature apk to upload on xiaomi store

Tags: android, apk, md5, xiaomi

I just wanted to upload my app on xiaomi app store and steps to create a signature build is not clear on develop dashboard there.
I googled but couldn't fine anything useful, can someone please help me to find any doc or steps I need to follow in order to create a xiaomi app store compatible apk file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following are the steps to get the signature from [MI dev](https://dev.mi.com/console/doc/detail?pId=882) website.

1.jarsigner signature method

You can use the jarsigner tool that comes with the JDK to complete the signing. The command format of the jarsigner tool is as follows:

```
jarsigner -verbose -keystore [path to your private key] -signedjar [path to file after signing] [path to unsigned file] [name of your certificate]
```

#jarsigner parameter description: The keystore parameter specifies the absolute path of your private key, for example: c:\mykeystore -signedjar The parameter specifies the absolute path where the signed apk file is stored, such as c:\signed.apk [unsigned file path] Specify the absolute path of the apk file to be signed, which is the one you downloaded from us. For example, c:\unsigned.apk [your certificate name] refers to the certificate name you set when you created the key.

---

2. Signing methods for Linux and Mac OS X platforms

Open the Terminal program and enter the decompressed directory of verification.zip downloaded from Xiaomi Developer Station, such as cd ~/Downloads/verification Use jarsigner to sign the command example:

```
jarsigner -verbose -keystore~/Workspace/mykeystore -signedjar ./signed.apk ./unsigned.apk xiaomi
```

---

3. Windows platform signature method

Open the "Command Prompt" program and enter the decompressed directory of verification.zip downloaded from the Xiaomi developer station, for example, cd C:\Downloads\verification

Example of signing command using jarsigner:

```
jarsigner -verbose -keystoreC:\Downloads\verification\mykeystore -signedjar signed.apk unsigned.apk xiaomi
```

The acquisition of the above signature methods should be completed with the assistance of R&D personnel.

Comment: What would be Passphrase for keystore while using 1st way?

Comment: If i'm not wrong it should be of your keystore